# Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor: 2016-12-15T15:58:03Z of type java.time.Instant

Tags: java-8

I have the following method and I am trying to compare a newly created OffsetDateTime to the below class:

```
public OffsetDateTime getCreatedDateFromToken(String token) {
        logger.debug("Entered getCreatedDateFromToken  "+token);
        OffsetDateTime o = (OffsetDateTime.from(getClaimsFromToken(token).getIssuedAt().toInstant()));
        logger.debug("OffSetTimeDate is "+o);

        return OffsetDateTime.from(getClaimsFromToken(token).getIssuedAt().toInstant());

    }
```

However I am getting the following error:

`java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor: 2016-12-15T15:58:03Z of type java.time.Instant`

---------------UPDATE ONE----------------

I tried the following but got the error below:

`ava.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor: 2016-12-15T19:51:57Z of type java.time.Instant`

```
@Override
    public OffsetDateTime getCreatedDateFromToken(String token) {
        logger.debug("Entered getCreatedDateFromToken  "+token);
        //OffsetDateTime o = (OffsetDateTime.from(getClaimsFromToken(token).getIssuedAt().toInstant()));
        OffsetDateTime oo = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.from(OffsetDateTime.from(getClaimsFromToken(token).getIssuedAt().toInstant())), ZoneOffset.UTC);
        //logger.debug("OffSetTimeDate is "+o);

        return oo;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try something like this to get the OffsetDateTime from Instant.

```
public OffsetDateTime getCreatedDateFromToken(String token) {
    logger.debug("Entered getCreatedDateFromToken  "+token);
    OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = getClaimsFromToken(token).getIssuedAt().toInstant().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    logger.debug("OffSetTimeDate is "+o);
    return offsetDateTime 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much but I do have one more question: Your solution outputs `2016-12-15T20:22:44Z` but `OffsetDateTime newlyGeneratedDate = OffsetDateTime.now();` generates `2016-12-15T15:22:44.780-05:00` so my test will fail. How can I get `.now` to work with your solution.

Comment: You can try OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)

Comment: That was it. Thank you